# What is the easiest way to download an entire Parse.com Image class to my desktop?

Tags: parse-platform

Question is pretty straightforward. I need to rename the images and change from .png to .jpg. All I really know is Swift, along with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: The answer is equally as straightforward. You download the images, convert them, and upload them again.  Seriously though, what have you tried already, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I have 7,000 plus images and I need to download them all at once. Do you know how to do that? I already have a program that can rename and change file type.

Comment: If you do a data export from Parse you'll get the URLs for each file in the exported JSON. You'll need to parse (ho ho ho) this and download each file separately. You'll then need to convert the image file, and then update each object that has the file attached to it, with the new file. Your best bet is to write a script to perform this as over the exported file. This isn't going to be a quick process if you have 7000 images.